# Showing a map is orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $T$ be a self-adjoint linear operator on $H$ =  $\Bbb{C}^n$.

Let $x_j$ be a unit eigen vector cooresponding to $\lambda_j$.

I am also given that $T$ has $n$ distinct eigen values.

Define $P: H \rightarrow H$ as

$P(x) = <x,x_j>.x_j$

Then how can I show that $P$ is orthogonal projection of $H$ onto the eigen space of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda_j$?

Comment: This is only true if $\lambda_j$ is a simple eigenvalue.

Comment: Suppose I am also given that there are n distinct eigen values of $T$. Then can I say that $\lambda_j$ is simple?

Comment: Yes (if $n$ is the dimension of $H$, as indicated). You have to prove two things: that $P$ is an orthogonal projection and that the range of $P$ is the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_j$. Where do you have difficulties?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not very well versed with linear algebra and studying a course on operator theory. I can see that there will be n LI eigen vectors corresponding to those n eigen values. But I can't see how the geometric multiplicity of each such eigen value will be 1. Could you please explain?

Comment: There can be no more than $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$, hence the geometric multiplicity of each eigenvalue cannot be bigger than $1$.

Comment: Let us say $x_j$ is an eigen vector corresponding to $\lambda_j$. I think my task is to show that if $y$ is any eigen vector corresponding to $\lambda_j$ then $y = cx_j$ for some constant c. I can clearly see that y = linear combination of all the x_j's but I can't see why is it of the type $cx_j$

Comment: If $B_j$ is a basis of the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_j$, then $\bigcup_j B_j$ is linearly independent. Since $H$ has dimension $n$, this means that every set $B_j$ can contain at most one element.

Comment: Done...Thanks a lot!!